# How to grab the binding value a label to the code behind in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a listview in which I have displayed all the employee name, address, and phone number.Now my task is to click on the label of the phone to make a phone call in xamarin forms.

Please help me to get the value of the binding label into the backend of the code.

```
<Label FontSize="14" x:Name="BtnCall" TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding Phone}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" >
    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer 
            Tapped="OnPhoneTapped">
        </TapGestureRecognizer>
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: Is the phone the phone number?

Comment: In code behind: `BtnCall.Text`, on view model: binded property `Phone`.

Comment: 1. Is the phone the phone number? 2. Is the label part of the listview?

Comment: I want to know that how can I get the value of label at the backend.
for example, I have a listview.In that listview i have one stack layout.inside the stack layout there is a binding label.

<Label FontSize="14" x:Name="lblCall" TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding Phone}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"/>

the result will be like this:

Phone : +1231241234
phone : +2341234123
phone: +1243241322

now I want to click on any of the rows and want to get the phone number at the backend.
 int num=lbCall.text;